# Delete error message in Intellij for import with an absolute path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, intellij-idea

I have set my React project to use absolute path in my import.
All works fine at the compilation but Intelij say me 'Module is not installed'.
How I can set my IDE Intellij for delete this error message ?

Comment: How did you set it up namely? the only path aliases supported are webpack aliases (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-alias)

Comment: I have add un file .env in my root level of my project with inside the line « NODE_PATH=src/ ». My problem is just a problem of configuration in IntelliJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up `NODE_PATH` in **Node.js** default run configuration: **Run | Edit Configurations...**, expand **Templates** node, select **Node.js** configuration, specify `NODE_PATH` in **Environment variables** field

Please see comments in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-19476